# How do i change my DNS host name using WIX

Tags: installation, wix, dns, hostname

How do i set my dns hostname for a iis asp.net website i am installing using WIX?
everything installs fine but i have to go to path 
http://localhost/EDSTR2F7

I want to be able to change it so i can get to the site by going
http://EDSTR2F7.myhostname.local

how do i do that using WIX?
is it part of the 
iis:WebSite,
iis:WebAddress,
iis:WebVirtualDir,
iis:WebApplication,  or
iis:WebDirProperties tags?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to create new sub website using [iis:WebSite](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/iis_xsd_website.htm) and make sure to assign to it the correct host name you want to map in using [iis:WebAddress](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_webaddress.htm)

Comment: How do you specify a hostname in iis:WebAddress?  It seems to take an ID, Port, Secure, and Header.

Comment: I did some searching and found an answer. It appears that the Header attribute of WebAddress is suppose to contain the desired hostname.